# How to position images before bibliography

Tags: floats, positioning

I successfully included `\usepackage[section]{placeins}`, which positions my figures just before bibliography in a very nice way, but there is another problem. The first page of my paper which contained title, abstract and some introduction, now only has title and everything is flashed at the second page. How can i fix that? If i remove `\usepackage[section]{placeins}` then the first page problem does not appear, but there are the figure between bibliography in the end.

Comment: Can you please show us a minimal working example?

Comment: I almost fixed it adding the below choice when calling placeins. But other weird placements appeared. Can i restrict the `\usepackage[section,below]{placeins}` only for some figures and not for other?

Comment: No idea. I'll note that the manual says "There is a package option “`[verbose]`” that causes many messages to be
written in the log file. It might be used to answer the question: ‘How did *that* get *there*?!?’", but I'm not familiar enough with this to even try guessing at a solution here.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you want to achieve? Do you just want all figures to appear below the main text but before the bibliography? Package `placeins` is not intended for such a thing; it only tries to keep the figures with the section in which they were defined.

Comment: I am  trying to position 3 figures which appear in my last section before the bibliography and not in between. With placeins that works but i see problems with huge gaps in previous positions of figures and text which did not exist without placeins

Comment: Have you tried removing all options to `placeins`, and just adding a `\FloatBarrier` before the bibliography? If that doesn't work, try making an example that we can test.

Comment: that worked finally